# How do I insert a Select Max from another table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

This is the code I have and I am not sure why it doesnt work

```
Insert INTO TEventGolfers (intGolferID, intEventID) 
    Values((Select MAX(intGolferID) From TGolfers),4)
```

I want to insert 4 as the EventID and the max golfer id from the table TGolfers as the foreign key golfer id in the EventGolfers Table

Comment: What's expected to happen if someone later today inserts into TGolfers an even higher intGolferID value? (Your data in TEventGolfers will be out of date.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this-

```
Insert INTO TEventGolfers (intGolferID, intEventID) 
    Select MAX(intGolferID),4 From TGolfers
```

Comment: The syntax used in OP should work as-is.

Comment: @SalmanA, yup, I know but this answer seems neater to me that OP's:)

Comment: More neat is not an answer!

Comment: @SalmanA, Okk, I'll keep it in my mind